# Include additional condition for a script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a script which sends a mail if a new row is added to a google spreadsheet. I like to add a second condition to let the script do it's work.

Now there's the condition `if (EmailSent != "gesendet")`, but I like to have additional condition, that the script checks another cell in the current row, if the're at least one or more mail addresses.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('xxx')
  var StartRow = 3;
  var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
  var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,33);//Added a new column for recipient email address
  var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++) {
    var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
    var Subject = "Neu: " + CurrentRow[7] + " für Ressort " + CurrentRow[5]  + " - "+ CurrentRow[6];
    var message = "<p><b>Ressort: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Textart: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Domain: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Thema: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" + "<p><b>fertig bis: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>";
    var EmailSent = CurrentRow[0];
    var SendTo = (CurrentRow[32])?CurrentRow[32]:"aaa@bbb.com" + "," + "xxx@yyy.com";//conditional (ternary) operator.  If CurrentRow[32] is there then use it otherwise use your default.
    if (EmailSent != "gesendet") {
      var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;
      ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 1).setValue("gesendet");
      MailApp.sendEmail({to: SendTo,cc: "",subject: Subject,htmlBody: message});
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe it's sufficient, if the script look for an "@" in the cell. The script should only work, if `if (EmailSent != "gesendet")` and in the cell is an "@".If there's no "@" the script should do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check `CurrentRow[32]` for the email address, you could change the if statement to:

```
if (EmailSent != "gesendet" && CurrentRow[32].match('@') != null ) {
```

This looks at the text in `CurrentRow[32]` and checks if it contains an '@'.